# make textbox data entry by calendat extender only - ASP.NET 4.0, C#

Tags: .net, textbox, calendar, asp.net-ajax

If using a calendar extender to enter a date to a textbox, is there any way to disable direct typing to the textbox? I want to force users to use the calendar rather than typing over a date and thereby possibly entering a date with an incorrect format.

thanks

T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theresa You can try with this

```
textbox.Enabled = false;
```

And you can set value with codeBehind

```
textbox.Text = yourCalendar.Value;
```

Comment: Hi, setting enabled=false or readOnly=true means that the data in the textbox cannot be changed either by typing or the calendar control. I could disbale it on the TextChanged event which would work, but then if the user input the wrong date they would have to save the record and go back into it to change it again.

Comment: Theresa you just disable text changed by user on your control, but you can change with code, just for user

Comment: I'am very happy to help you Thank's Theresa

Answer (score 1):

Add onkeydown="return false" to textbox in aspx.

Answer (score 1):

Older post, but I found [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/text-box-should-accepts-only-date-using-calendar-extender1) solution that worked perfectly for me:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{    
if (!IsPostBack)    
{    
 txtDate.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");    
}    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set the ReadOnly attribute to "true" of that text box.For example: textBox1.ReadOnly ="true"